# If $q$ is a polynomial such that $q(T)=0$, then q is a polynomial multiple of $p$

Tags: linear-algebra

I stumbled into the following theorem in [Axler Sheldon's paper](http://www.axler.net/DwD.pdf) page 7 (Minimal Polynomial):

> **Theorem 4.1**  Let $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_m$ be the distinct eigenvalues of $T$, let $U_j$ denote the set of generalized
>   eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_j$, and let $\alpha_j$ be the
>   smallest positive integer such that $(T-\lambda_jI)^{\alpha_j}v=0$ for
>   every $v\in U_j$. Let
>
> $$p(z) = (z-\lambda_1)^{\alpha_1}\cdots(z-\lambda_m)^{\alpha_m}.$$
>
> If $q$ is a polynomial such that $q(T)=0$, then $q$ is a
>   polynomial multiple of $p$.
>
> Proof:
>
> Suppose $q$ is a polynomial such that $q(T)=0$. If we show that $q$ is
>   a polynomial multiple of each $(z-\lambda_j)^{\alpha_j}$, then the
>   claim will hold. To do this, fix $j$. The polynomial $q$ has the form
>
> $$q(z) =
>  c(z-r_1)^{\delta_1}\cdots(z-r_M)^{\delta_M}\color{red}{(z-\lambda_j)^{\delta}},$$
>
> where $c\in\mathbb{C}$, the $r_k$'s are complex numbers all different
>   from $\lambda_j$, the $\delta_k$'s are positive integers, and $\delta$
>   is a non-negative integer. If $c=0$, we are done, so assume that
>   $c\neq0$. Suppose $v\in U_j$. Then $(T-\lambda_j)^\delta v$ is also in
>   $U_j$ (Theorem 3.11(b) in the paper). Now
>
> $$c(T-r_1I)^{\delta_1}\cdots(T-r_MI)^{\delta_M}(T-\lambda_jI)^{\delta}v=q(T)v=0,$$
>
> and $(T-r_1I)^{\delta_1}\cdots(T-r_MI)^{\delta_M}$ is injective on
>   $U_j$ (by theorem 3.11(d) in paper). Thus $(T-\lambda_j)^{\delta}v=0$.
>   Because $v$ was an arbitrary element of $U_j$, this implies that
>   $\alpha_j\leq\delta$. Thus $q$ is a polynomial multiple of
>   $(z-\lambda_j)^{\alpha_j}$ and claim holds $\blacksquare$

My question is the part I've highlighted in red. Why does the polynomial have the given form? Is the red part in $q$ necessary? It is only stated about $q$ that $q(T)=0$, that is all the information given...so why does the author state that $q$ has the given form. Is this an assumption or a must be?

Please check the reference I gave if you need more information.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: it's just that $\delta$ is a non-negative integer, so that it can be $0$. So any polynomial $P$ can be written as $P = Q(z-\lambda_j)^\delta$, since either $z-\lambda_j$ divide $P$, either it does not and you can just take $\delta = 0$. The point of the proof is to show that actually $\delta \geq \alpha_j \geq 1$

Comment: Thank you for your help! =) Understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $q$ is an arbitrary polynomial, then there exists finitely many $r_i \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $q(r_i)=0$ and $q(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \not\in \{ r_i\}$.
In this case, we can write $q(z) = c ( z- r_1)^{d_1}(z- r_2)^{d_2} \cdots ( z- r_n)^{d_n}$ with $d_i > 0$ for all $i$.

However, we want to show that $(z- \lambda_j)$ divides $q$. Now, if for example $r_1 = \lambda_j$, then we have
\begin{align}
q(z) = c ( z- r_1)^{d_1}(z- r_2)^{d_2} \cdots ( z- r_n)^{d_n} = c(z-r_2)^{d_2} \cdots (z-r_n)^{d_n} (z- \lambda_j)^{d_1}.
\end{align}
So we have the desired form with $\delta = d_1 > 0$.
In case $r_i \neq \lambda_j$ for all $i$, we note that $x^0=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$, so we can multiply $q$ with $(z-\lambda_j)^0$ to find
\begin{align}
q(z) = c ( z- r_1)^{d_1}(z- r_2)^{d_2} \cdots ( z- r_n)^{d_n}  (z- \lambda_j)^{0}.
\end{align}
So again, we have the desired form with $\delta = 0$.

Thus in all cases we have 
\begin{align}
q(z) = c ( z- r_1)^{d_1}(z- r_2)^{d_2} \cdots ( z- r_n)^{d_n}  (z- \lambda_j)^{\delta}.
\end{align}
with $d_i > 0$ and $\delta \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So did I understand correctly the point of the  proof. We simply add the $(z-\lambda_j)^\delta$ because we can do this without changing $q$ and then we simply solve the conditions on $\delta$. As in the proof that $\alpha_j \leq \delta$. Is this correct?

Comment: @jjepsuomi correct.

Comment: @jjepsuomi we don't really "add it", since it can be (and, seeing the conclusion of the proof, it actually is) already here in the polynomial $q$. The point is that any polynomial $P$ can be written in a unique manner as the product of $(z - r_i)^{d_i}$ with $d_i > 0$ and $(z - \lambda_j)^\delta$ with $\delta \geq 0$, even if $(z - \lambda_j)$ does not divide $P$. But if it does divide, we don't add it : if $P = (z - \lambda_j)$ for example, we don't write it $(z - \lambda_j) \times (z - \lambda_j)^\delta$ with $\delta = 0$, but just say that $\delta = 1$ instead.

Comment: @yago Thank you for the additional clarification! =) Appreciate it